# Magento 1.9 : Tax calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I have added product price tax inclusive in the price column and applied a tax class says 5% tax.
On the frontend, catalog price should not increase in the cart, but when I'm adding the product into cart, row total, subtotal and grand total coming inclusive of 5%.

For eg. Catalog price added with product INR 654 (incl. tax)
Tax 5% - 32.70 INR
Row total - 686.70 INR
Subtotal - 686.70 INR
Grand Total - 686.70 INR

But Row total, subtotal, grand total should be 654 INR.

Here is my store's tax setting https://prnt.sc/pzd0j8

How to get this in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

I've repeated your tax config on Magento 1.9.0 and tax is calculated as you expect (product card price = row total = subtotal = grand total = 654).

Do you use default theme or changed one? Can you check these values direct in database?

Comment: I'm setting custom price in cart of product after add to cart event as "$item->setCustomPrice()".

Comment: Did you check `price_incl_tax` in `sales_flat_quote_item` table?

Comment: `price_incl_tax` is the same as `row_total_incl_tax`.

When I add custom price (through AdminPanel) it is also the same.

Comment: I see that `custom_price` is amount without tax, so probably you should `setCustomPrice(622,86)` to get what you want.

Comment: To get `price_excl_tax` for your amount you can use `calcTaxAmount()` from `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation `

Comment: Custom price is with tax that is 654 INR, Taking this price from another party and setting for the product on add to cart button event and product is virtual type.

Comment: `Custom price is with tax that is 654 INR` and that the reason why you get `686.70 INR` in subtotal. Magento expects `custom_price` to be without tax.

Comment: I tried to set `custom price without tax`, but magento recalculate tax on `custom price without tax` and update `subtotal`.